# CarrierWave uploader default image using parent model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using CarrierWave uploader for user avatars in my rails project and I'm currently providing a default URL (randomly chosen from 4 choices) for users who didn't upload their pictures. As suggested by the CarrierWave [README](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url), I've implemented it as thus:

```rb
class UserAvatarUploader < ImageUploader
  def default_url(*args)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("avatars/default_avatar_#{rand(4).to_s}.png")
  end
end
```

Since it is a random function, the problem here is that the user's avatar changes every time the page is reloaded. Ideally I would like to derive a number from the username of the user so that his/her default avatar stays consistent. How might I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: rather than using `rand` you can use lets say  `user.id` or something if you want it to be unique?

Comment: @uDaY Yes that would work too. Essentially I just want to get user information from within the `default_url` method but I don't know how to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved it. Essentially I was stuck because I couldn't find a way to get user information from within the `default_url` method. I later found out that the variable `model` is available and it refers to the user. Here's my final code:

```
class UserAvatarUploader < ImageUploader
  def default_url(*args)
    number = model.id % 4
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("avatars/default_avatar_#{number}.png")
  end
end
```